# Consigo obtener el mayor y menor pero no el return de la diferencia

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, condiciones

Hola perdón no había formulado bien la pregunta.

La pregunta es: Obtener del array "arr" el número mayor y el menor y devolver la resta entre los mismos

*NOTA*: No utilizar los métodos "**min**" y "**max**" de "**Math**".

```
function mayorMenosMenor(arr) { 
  var mayor = [];
  var menor = arr[0];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     if(arr[i] > mayor){
        mayor = arr[i]
     }
     if(arr[i] < menor){
         menor = [arr[i]];
     }
   }
   return mayor - menor;  
};
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar el código en formato texto y no en imagen. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia la imagen por el texto. De lo contrario tu pregunta podría terminar cerrada por falta de un [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: No veo que el código esté metido en una función... así que a dónde estás devolviéndolo? `return` no imprime algo en pantalla, lo *"devuelve"*. Pero si no estás dentro de un bloque de código, no tiene sentido porque lo que haces es terminar el programa con un código X (el resultado de tu resta) y cuando un programa terminar con algo que no sea 0, se interpreta como error.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Perdón gente, es mi primera pregunta ahí lo edite lo mejor que pude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías probar este código:

```js
function diferencia(){
var arr = [5,3,10,6, 15, 1];
var mayor = 0;
var menor = arr[0];

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  if(mayor < arr[i]){
    mayor = arr[i];
  }
  if (arr[i] < menor){
    menor = arr[i];
  }
}
resultado = mayor - menor;
return resultado;

}

var resultado = diferencia();
console.log(resultado);
```

Para comprobar el numero mayor, creamos una variable igualada a 0 y la vamos comparando con todos los elementos del array, si la variable **mayor** es menor que el elemento del array se va sustituyendo por el elemento del array que es mayor.

Para comprobar el menor, le damos de valor a la variable **menor** el primer valor del array para poder ir comparando con el resto. Si el elemento del array es menor que el que tenemos en menor se sustituye.

Esta sería la forma más sencilla de lograrlo sin usar Max y Min.

Para la diferencia tienes que llamar a la función y guardarlo en una variable para recibir el resultado del return.

Compruébalo y cualquier duda consultame.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, si eso me da bien lo que me sale error es cuando quiero hacer un return al final

Comment: Si perdona lo arreglo

Comment: ok gracias amigo

Comment: De nada, ya tienes actualizado el código en la respuesta. Coméntame si te funcionó. @Raul

Comment: Sí el código que me pasaste funciona bien, pero no entiendo porque el return seguido del último if no funciona, osea me refiero a que la función terminé ahí.

Comment: De qué return estamos hablando? Te refieres a hacer un return después del if pero dentro del for? Tanto en tú código como en el mio esta después. El return debe estar siemrpe al final de la función ya que cualquier código que pongas después del return dentro de la función no se ejecutará @Raul

Comment: function mayorMenosMenor(arr) {
    var mayor = 0;
    var menor = arr[0];
    var resultado = 0;
    
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
      if(mayor < arr[i]){
        mayor = arr[i];
      }
      if (arr[i] < menor){
        menor = arr[i];
      }
    }
    resultado = mayor - menor;
    return resultado;
}; Este es el return que no entiendo porque no funciona, esta fuera del for

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu duda respecto al código. Dime exactamente que no entiendes del return. Porque tal cuál me lo has puesto funciona correctamente si le estas pasando un array a la función claro @Raul

Comment: Ah pensé que el return fuera del for daba error porque probé en un editor de código y no me funcionaba, quizás escribí algo mal entonces. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Entonces ya te funciona? Si es así agradecería que dieras por correcta la respuesta :) @Raul

Comment: Si amigo, ya le di correcta, muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada, a ti :) @Raul